# Function does not stop executing after return statement

Tags: c++, function, return

I am working in C++ and have written a function but it does not stop the execution after the return statement.

```
BSTNode* search(BSTNode* root, int data)
{
    BSTNode* newroot=root;
    int count = 1;
    if (root->data == data)
    {
        newroot=root;
        count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        search(root->left, data);
        if (count != 0)
            search(root->right, data);
    }
    return newroot;
}
```

How can I make it stop executing after returning the value?

Comment: "it does not stop the execution after the return statement" - what do you mean by that? The `return` statement is specifically designed to end the execution of a function - there's absolutely no way that the _same_ function frame continues execution after `return`. This function is recursive, so it will call itself (and disregard the return value) though.

Comment: An observation not directly related to the question that also applies to @RemyLebeau's solution is that you're ignoring the binary searchability of the tree. Presumably the BST is in sorted order, right? You could use a comparison between `data` and `root->data` to determine whether to search `root->left` or `root->right` instead of always checking left first then right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `count` variable is useless and should be removed.  The recursive calls to `search()` do not update it, so `if (count != 0)` is always evaluated as true.

You are also ignoring the return value of the recursive `search()` calls to stop the search once a matching node is found.

And you are ignoring the possibility of null pointers being present in the tree.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
BSTNode* search(BSTNode* root, int data)
{
    if (!root)
        return nullptr;

    if (root->data == data)
        return root;

    BSTNode *node = search(root->left, data);
    if (!node)
        node = search(root->right, data);

    return node;
}
```

Comment: It works fine, thank you so much. What does `!root` or `!node` means

Comment: @MAHAJAVED ! Is the logical NOT operator.

Comment: @MAHAJAVED when a pointer is null, applying the `!` operator on it returns true, otherwise false. `if (!root)` is just a simpler alternative to writing `if (root == nullptr)`, etc. On the other hand, pointers are implicitly convertible to `bool`, false if nullptr otherwise true, so `if (root)` is a simpler alternative to writing `if (root != nullptr)`